# .bashrc file not reflecting changes

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, cluster-computing

I am setting a single node cluster for Hadoop on Ubuntu. After downloading Hadoop and setting its path in .bashrc file, when I run the command 
**echo $HADOOP_HOME** in a new terminal, it doesn't give any output. What is the reason for such behavior?

These are the lines I added to .bashrc

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_91"
set PATH ="$PATH:JAVA_HOME/bin"
export HADOOP_HOME="/home/neel_shah/hadoop-2.7.2"
PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export PATH
```

Comment: post your .bashrc content

Comment: Did you logout and re-login of the current session? or type source ~/.bashrc

Comment: yes I opened a new terminal to check the echo command

Comment: Is your shell really `bash`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

command, probably will solve your problem without needing logout and login again

fix your .bashrc as following

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_91"
PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
export HADOOP_HOME="/home/neel_shah/hadoop-2.7.2"
PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export PATH
```

save .bashrc, then in terminal run command

```
exit
```

this will log you out
then login back using your username and password
it should be ok

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But when I open a new terminal, it doesn't give the output. Any reason or solution for that?